# ionic 3.9 localnotification and androidx

Tags: ionic-framework, android-support-library, localnotification

in order to use a new plugin, I had to update my cordova version to 9.0.0, and I also updated my android version to 28. 
My problem is now I can't compile my project because of the cordova plugin "localnotification" (https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications).

I have a bunch of errors (maybe 150/200) related to android support library v4, like :

```
error: package android.support.v4.content does not exist
or
cannot find symbol public class AssetProvider extends FileProvider {
                                                      ^
```

Because I updgraded android, I had to migrate to androidX too. I did it by adding this in `gradle.properties`  :

```
android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true
```

But now I'm unable to compile my app without all these errors above. I found something saying that we should add these lines in the `.gradle` of the plugin :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' 
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
```

I did it without success.
Any other ideas ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Oh and I tried to remove the android.useAndroidX=true and android.enableJetifier=true from the gradle.properties but I get a duplicate class error : Program type already present: android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel

Comment: ok I finally found the solution thanks to this post 
 !!! https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/migrating-ionic-app-to-androidx/160844/2